# How to use React Hook in Redux Saga?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, redux-saga

I am setting language for my app. But I have a problem.

I use `React.useContext()` to set language. But when I fix it in saga's toast, it log:

> [Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body
> of a function component. This could happen for one of the following
> reasons:
>
> 1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
> 2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
> 3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug
>    and fix this problem.]

So **can I use** it in **saga**? If **yes**, **how** should I use it? If **no**, can you suggest me a solution.

---

The final solution is props message from saga.

---

This is a function of my 'toast.js' file:

```
export function toastLoginSuccess() {
  ToastAndroid.show(
    LANGUAGES.toastLoginSuccess,
    ToastAndroid.SHORT,
    ToastAndroid.TOP,
  );
}
```

with LANGUAGE is `import * as LANGUAGES from '../asset/language';`

and `toastLoginSuccess` is `export const toastLoginSuccess = 'Login success!';`

I want change it to `const LANGUAGES = React.useContext(LanguageContext).language;`

And saga is a file similar to:

```
export function* fetchSigninSaga(action) {
  try {
    // ...
    yield Toast.toastLoginSuccess())
  } catch (error) {
    // ...
    yield Toast.toastLoginFail();
  }
}
```

Comment: React hooks can only be called in function components and other React hooks. You won't be able to directly call a React hook from a saga.

Comment: :/ Do you have a solution for my problem @DrewReese?
I try to fix it for about 2 weeks but still cumber

Comment: Or should I use another way to set app's language?

Comment: I don't have familiarity enough with sagas to even make an educated guess, unfortunately.

Comment: The final solution is props message from saga.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to inject your context in saga first, below is the way to achieve it,

```
import createSagaMiddleware from "redux-saga";

const userService = createUserService(...);

const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware({
    context: LanguageContext
});

sagaMiddleware.run(rootSaga);
```

Once you have injected, you the use it in the below manner,

```
import { getContext } from "redux-saga/effects";

export function* loadUsersSagas(action) {
    const languageContext = yield getContext("languageContext");
    const language = yield languageContext.getLanguage();
    ...
}
```

For more on this you can check, [getContext](https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/api/#getcontextprop)

Comment: Tks you. I'm planning to prop message from saga. Because I save language state to AsyncStorage. it takes a long time to fix. I will try your way.

Comment: how can I use custom hooks into saga

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a **React Hook in the React Saga generator function** (not just this example) you will have to create a function to run your hook outside the saga *generator function* and then call the function inside the saga *generator function*.

Example

```js
const success = ()=> { 
   // your hook or any other hook 
   Toast.toastLoginSuccess()
}
const failed = ()=> { 
   // your hook or any other hook
   Toast.toastLoginFail()
}
```

You can then call your functions

```js
export function* fetchSigninSaga(action) {
  try {
    // ...
    yield success()
  } catch (error) {
    // ...
    yield failed();
  }
}
```